# How do i recover my password in ubuntu

Tags: password-recovery

My dad has forgotten his *Password*. He knows his *username*. We have tried every thing  and he needs that account.

Is there anything he/we can do to reset/retrieve the password? 
We have read way to do the Recovery but don't quite understand them.

Comment: Here is the problem with Linux,and its community. The answers are are correct, but simply re-itterating what the OP has likely already read. So my question for thes op is what step is causing confusion? You will be best if you are able to follow the instructions from another device.

Answer (score 2):

Reboot the host into Recovery mode https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode and follow the directions to get it into `Drop to root shell prompt` and even follow the directions to mount the drive as read/write.  After that is complete, type in at the prompt to set the password for him:

`passwd username`

Where you replace **username** with his username, and that will allow you to set the password for his user account.  When that is completed, type in `reboot` at the prompt to reboot the system so it will come back up to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Enter recovery at grub menu...

Then choose root shell prompt..

Then enter

```
> mount -n -o remount,rw / passwd username_here
```

Choose new password then type reboot and you're done.

you can also check out this youtube tutorial

> `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGpvCZO2oOc`